# SystemJS imported class file not found

Tags: typescript, systemjs

This is the system configuration code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        SystemJS.config({
            "defaultJSExtensions" : true
        });

        SystemJS.import('./User.js').then(function(m) {
            console.log(m);
        });
    </script>
```

I have imported user class file and user class file will import address class. Below is the code I used:

```
export class Address {

public address : string = "Address";

}
```

I have imported this class in User.ts file like below:

```
import { Address } from "./Address"
```

If I run this code, 'address class not found' error is shown.

I have followed the instructions provided by SystemJS. But it's not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the generated javascript files?

Comment: Hi, I have added typescript code and javascript code in below link
https://jsfiddle.net/vanarajaz/b89s4nr4/1/#
https://jsfiddle.net/vanarajaz/nn9b2pe7/